# Infinite query animation not working with delays

Tags: jquery, animation

```
function enemy () {
            this.obj;
            this.create = function () {
                var obj_string = '<img src="img/char.jpg" class="enemy" style="position:absolute; left:' + this.P1[0] + 'px; top: ' + this.P1[1] + 'px; height:' + 100 + 'px;width:auto;">';
                this.obj = $($.parseHTML(obj_string));
                $("#layer_enemies").append(this.obj);
                this.anim();
            };
            this.anim = function () {
                $(this.obj).delay(this.WaitAtP1).show(0);
                $(this.obj).animate({left: '570px'},1000,function(){
                    $(this.obj).delay(this.WaitAtP2).show(0);
                    $(this.obj).animate({left: '200px'},1000,function(){
                        this.anim();
                    });
                });
            };
            this.create();
        };
```

The animation is stopping after the first move to the right :(
i cannot figure out why..

Comment: the 'this' inside the complete method is a jQuery Object, not your enemy Object. So this.anim() goes wrong, should throw some error too.

Comment: No it is not throwing any errors thats the problem. I only wanted this.obj to be a query object..

Comment: Ah I see. But I think @axel.michel got it right :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with the `this`, inside the jQuery function, `this` is not longer the reference to your object / class but a jQuery object. Therefore you have to do it like this:

```
this.anim = function () {
    var that = this;
    $(this.obj).delay(this.WaitAtP1).show(0);
    $(this.obj).animate({left: '570px'},1000,function(){
        $(that.obj).delay(that.WaitAtP2).show(0);
        $(that.obj).animate({left: '200px'},1000,function(){
            that.anim();
        });
    });
};
```

[Working demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKZoqO).

Or you use the jQuery.proxy method (available since 1.4).

Comment: Thank you so much, "this" is such a mean word ;)